# Valid JSON file but bad structure? (Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, structure

This is my first time using JSON. I have to read objects from a JSON file which I have no input over(structure/format). I have been using http://json2csharp.com/ to understand what objects I could get from it.
**Based on the examples below, is the structure in this file bad?** 
I have changed the actual field names in the example, structure otherwise the same as the file I have to read from. There are hundreds of these objects(FRUITS) and will be many more.
Should I use RegExp to get a better JSON structure before parsing the JSON file?

Original file:

```
{
"FRUITS": {
    "BANANA": {
        "category"      : "FRUITS",
        "fruit_type"    : "Peelable",
        "description"   : "Yellow soft fruit",
        "identifier"    : "BANANA",
        "attributes": [ {
                "description"   : "hardness",
                "value"         : 3
            }, {
                "description"   : "smell",
                "strength"      : 1,
                "max_value"     : 10
            }, {
                "argument"      : "PRESS",
                "description"   : "Press fruit",
                "strength"      : 2
        } ],
        "physical_type": "yellow"
    },
    "APPLE": {
        "category"      : "FRUITS",
        "fruit_type"    : "Peelable",
        "description"   : "Red hard fruit",
        "identifier"    : "APPLE",
        "attributes"    : [ {
                "description"   : "hardness",
                "value"         : 10
            }, {
                "description"   : "smell",
                "strength"      : 1,
                "max_value"     : 10
            }, {
                "argument"      : "PRESS",
                "description"   : "Press fruit",
                "strength"      : 2
        } ],
        "physical_type" : "red"
    }
}
```

}

Classes generated are:

```
        public class Attribute
    {
         public string description { get; set; }
         public int value { get; set; }
         public int? strength { get; set; }
         public int? max_value { get; set; }
         public string argument { get; set; }
    }

    public class BANANA
    {
         public string category { get; set; }
         public string fruit_type { get; set; }
         public string description { get; set; }
         public string identifier { get; set; }
         public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
         public string physical_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attribute2
    {
         public string description { get; set; }
         public int value { get; set; }
         public int? strength { get; set; }
         public int? max_value { get; set; }
         public string argument { get; set; }
    }

    public class APPLE
    {
         public string category { get; set; }
         public string fruit_type { get; set; }
         public string description { get; set; }
         public string identifier { get; set; }
         public List<Attribute2> attributes { get; set; }
         public string physical_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class FRUITS
    {
         public BANANA BANANA { get; set; }
         public APPLE APPLE { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
         public FRUITS FRUITS { get; set; }
    }
```

If I change it a little bit to:

```
{
"FRUITS": [{        
        "category"      : "FRUITS",
        "fruit_type"    : "Peelable",
        "description"   : "Yellow soft fruit",
        "identifier"    : "BANANA",
        "attributes": [ {
                "description"   : "hardness",
                "value"         : 3
            }, {
                "description"   : "smell",
                "strength"      : 1,
                "max_value"     : 10
            }, {
                "argument"      : "PRESS",
                "description"   : "Press fruit",
                "strength"      : 2
        } ],
        "physical_type": "yellow"
    },{
        "category"      : "FRUITS",
        "fruit_type"    : "Peelable",
        "description"   : "Red hard fruit",
        "identifier"    : "APPLE",
        "attributes"    : [ {
                "description"   : "hardness",
                "value"         : 10
            }, {
                "description"   : "smell",
                "strength"      : 1,
                "max_value"     : 10
            }, {
                "argument"      : "PRESS",
                "description"   : "Press fruit",
                "strength"      : 2
            } ],
            "physical_type" : "red"
    }]
```

}

I get the following classes:

```
        public class Attribute
    {
         public string description { get; set; }
         public int value { get; set; }
         public int? strength { get; set; }
         public int? max_value { get; set; }
         public string argument { get; set; }
    }

    public class FRUIT
    {
         public string category { get; set; }
         public string fruit_type { get; set; }
         public string description { get; set; }
         public string identifier { get; set; }
         public List<Attribute> attributes { get; set; }
         public string physical_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
         public List<FRUIT> FRUITS { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: second structure looks much better. Is there a problem? What is your question?

Comment: Yes, I have no input over the structure of the file. I am in tight situation. Need to read a lot of data but I don't want to start coding C# based on that JSON structure. Is there some JSON lingo for the structure in the original example? I have tried Googling "JSON good practises" to find concrete examples but cannot find any that would say that this is not a good JSON file (although it is valid).

Comment: If you can't modify the JSON structure (you have to deal with what you get) the you should read it in a matchung class structure, convert these object to something better (in memory) and work with the converted objects.

Comment: Well I have been contemplating modifying it using RegExp and then parse it with Json.NET.

Comment: There are hundreds of these objects.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: Json.Net (newtonSoft) has a library to read JSON Elements from JSON Files. Use this instaed of regexp's. Avoid a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first structure in your question is produced dynamically (i.e. there is a varying number of fruits with ever changing names) then

1. The designer of this structure did a bad job (irrelevant here)
2. You could read the JSON File token by token and *parse* it into
   some objects. This is nicely supported my NewtonSoft's JSON library.

Comment: Yes it is dynamically produced. This I know. OK I will have to figure something out. I tried parsing token by token but darn that is cumbersome,  having to know where I am at all the time and considering how easy it could be if just the structure was modified a little bit.

Comment: Parsing tokens isn't too hard if you do it right. Get read something about "building a compiler" (the token parser part).

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you should definitely not use RegExes or or any other direct string manipulation to mutate some valid JSON.

Parse the JSON into an object graph and transform the object graph using some c# to get the structure you want. To perform the transform consider the use of the `System.Linq` namespace.

**Why?** Doing this with linq is easier to write, easier to maintain, and not fraught with the pitfalls associated with string manipulation. What is more, significant effort has been put into modern JSON Parsers to make them reliable and fast. Attempts at a specialized partial implementation of a parser, to perform a specific task will not benefit from this effort.

---

**Caveat**

If the file contains invalid JSON, (e.g. its not JSON but close to) then string manipulation will probably be necessary, JSON parsers will likely be incompatible with non JSON.

I can envision some very specialized case where a Regex might offer a performance benefit, I'd have to test it. However, this does not apply in your situation.